# Zero copy in Qt client program

Tags: c++, qt, zero-copy

I am trying to implement zero copy approach in my client progrm where I will recieve a large amount of data from server.Here is my client program:
//Client.h

```
#ifndef CLIENT_H
#define CLIENT_H

#include <QtNetwork/QTcpSocket>
#include <QObject>
#include <QString>

class Client: public QObject
{
Q_OBJECT
public:
  Client(QObject* parent = 0);
  ~Client();
  void start(QString address, quint16 port);
public slots:
  void startTransfer();
private:
  QTcpSocket client;
};

#endif // CLIENT_H
```

//Client.cpp

```
#include "client.h"
#include <QtNetwork/QHostAddress>

Client::Client(QObject* parent): QObject(parent)
{
  connect(&client, SIGNAL(connected()),
    this, SLOT(startTransfer()));
}

Client::~Client()
{
  client.close();
}

void Client::start(QString address, quint16 port)
{
  QHostAddress addr(address);
  client.connectToHost(addr, port);
}

void Client::startTransfer()
{
    virtual QByteArray client::readanydata();

}
```

readanydata() should be replaced by any other API,as read() and readall() use memory copy they are not suitable for zero copy approach.client is instance of QTcpsocket.what should I use here.any suggestion,as I am not getting any API or should I write my own function.If I have to write my own function how will it call transmitfile() api.

Comment: Qt does not implement a zero copy at this point. You'll need to write your own implementation specific to the operating system you're working on.

Comment: @RobbieE: thanks for reply,I have to write a platform independent function,so what should I do?